# I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an Intel Nuc 10 gen i3 with a M2 1TB storage

Tags: drivers, intel, m2

Also, I want to create two partitions, / and /home into this M2 storage disk.

I have read a lot of people saying that Intel Nuc Bios (especially in the 10 and 11 generations) is troublesome with Linux and that the installation gets tricky. Other people say that M.2 didn't work properly with Linux. Others say that drivers (like Ethernet, audio, USB) didn't work well with Linux. I suspect they just are a little group that had issues, but I don't sure.

So, I would want to know your experiences with it.

Will I have any problem installing Ubuntu 20.04 on a Nuc 10 gen?

I don't want to have to do a lot of steps to get it... I just want to install Ubuntu normally. I'm not a Linux programmer (but neither an entirely beginner), I just want the Nuc for writing, gaming, and browsing on the Internet.

Thanks in advance!

PD: English is my second language ;)

Comment: Rather than 20.04, use 21.04 for the newer hardware. The LTS *should* be okay, but the newest release has better hardware support overall. Before installing, be sure to “test drive” the OS using a Live USB. This will let you know ahead of time if you will need to invest time looking for drivers or applying custom hardware configurations. If everything is good with the Live USB, you can install the OS from there and you should be golden 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to try;

Also Ubuntu develop a specific spinoff for the NUC
https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc-desktop

then upgrade your ubuntu to 20.04
You can also upgrade from the shell with the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```